# using UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: iphone, objective-c

On simulator UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum cannot save movie into photo album unless photo album is open. Can it? How can I check if Photo Album is running and run it silently from my app? Chances are that on a real iPhone/Pad it will be already running but just in case...?

My movie is in Resources of my app. I want to copy it to album. Here is the methods that I put in my AppDelegate.m to accomplish that:

```
 -(void)downloadVideo:(NSString *)sampleMoviePath{
if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(sampleMoviePath)){
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(sampleMoviePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError: contextInfo:), sampleMoviePath);
}
}

-(void)video:(NSString *)videoPath didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo{
NSLog(@"Finished with error: %@", error);
}
```

I call it like this:

```
NSString *sampleMediaPathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movie_01.m4v"];
[self downloadVideo:sampleMediaPathFromApp];
```

> Error message that I get:
>   Finished saving video with error: Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3310 "Data unavailable" UserInfo=0x564ab10 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Launch the Photos application, NSLocalizedDescription=Data unavailable}

Naturally, if I open Photo album and then run my app it works fine.

Thanks a lot for your input.
BG

----edits----

I have edited the code so it is more readable - sorry I do not have an answer, but it is a good question - I had to put this here or else I could not submit the changes. --jwk82

Comment: Welcome to SO, read the FAQ and also format your questions for better readabilty and responses.

Comment: Why don't you just get rid of the if statement in the downloadView: method and see if that works.

Comment: I switched to XCode 4.2, now it saves video all right, but still returns an error 0x0. Well I can live with that, I guess.

Answer (score -2):

You can save it as..

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
```

Comment: `ALAssetsLibrary` was deprecated on iOS 9.0

Comment: @Fantini the answer was made one year back